# MySQL UTF8 Database migration

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, migration

I'm having problems to migrate an utf8 database to another server... Each source and destination table has a `"DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"`.

I use mysqldump to dump data and `mysql < file.sql` to import but when in the source table i have "España", in the destination i get "EspaÃ±a".

I read some guides, i used `--default-character-set=latin1` to export and import, but the problem remains. 
I also tried a `--default-character-set=utf8` to import, but the result is: "Espa", data is truncated to the first occurrence of a multibyte char.

I need help!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's very important to make sure the client is set to UTF8. Confusingly, it's not the same as setting your database to UTF8. Open /etc/my.cnf and make sure you have default-character-set = utf8 under [mysql] not just under [mysqld]

Now you should be able to pipe UTF8 dumps directly into the mysql client. I also recommend using the option --hex-blob on the mysqldump command as mysqldump is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 ./file >file.utf8
mysql --default-charset=utf8 < file.utf8
```

If it does not work i advise you to import data then convert it

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

What is the `collation` of each table? Sounds to me like the 2nd table is still encoded ISO-8859-1 or similar.

Plus, what tool are you using to look at the destination data? Are you sure the connection that tool uses is UTF-8 as well?

Comment: Here is the SHOW CREATE TABLE code:

CREATE TABLE `Country` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

how do i get the collation ?

Comment: i use --default-character-set=utf8  to import data using mysql < file

Comment: to look at destination data i use mysql client, and yes, i'm sure it is a utf8 connection:

| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |

Comment: Character sets and table/column collations are not the same. What collation are your tables/columns? What does DESCRIBE say? Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html